# Show woocommerce errors

Tags: woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and want to show wocommerce error messages in specific place of my theme, for example under submit button.

I know wocommerce error messages come from here:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-error">
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But, when i put this code in my page (for example edit-my-address.php page), its giving error!
What is working or simple code for showing messages in woocommerce?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be better if you can tell us what you are trying do in edit-my-address.php page for example… What message do you need to throw and when *(or for what)*?

Answer (score 4):

you can use both methods here..

```
woocommerce_show_messages();
wc_print_notices();
```

You can also show woocommerce custom notices according to your condition like...

```
wc_add_notice( 'This is a Success notice', 'success' );
wc_add_notice( 'This is a Error notice', 'error' );
wc_add_notice( 'This is a \'Notice\' notice\'', 'notice' );
```

Comment: As of WC 2.1, `woocommerce_show_messages()` is deprecated in favour of `wc_print_notices()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this piece of code to functions.php of your child theme

```
add_shortcode('woocommerce_notices', function($attrs) {
    if (wc_notice_count() > 0) {
    ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-notices-shortcode woocommerce">
    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
});
```

And then use it as a shortcode [woocommerce_notices] in any desired post or page, or use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>` in a desired PHP template.

Tested and works. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here is a solution.

Try to use the following piece of code (taken from the original file here: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php)

```php
<?php
  /**
   * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
   *
   * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
   * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
   */
  do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you missed to add this line of code:

```
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php` file inside your child theme (or main theme if there is no child).

```js
add_shortcode('woocommerce_notices', function($attrs) {
    if (function_exists('wc_notice_count') && wc_notice_count() > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-notices-shortcode">
            <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $(window).on("load", function(){
                    // You can execute some js here
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
        // You can execute some php here
        wc_clear_notices();
    }
});
```

Then add a shortcode to your page as:

```
[woocommerce_notices]
```

The notices and the code will get executed wherever you paste the shortcode.